# Customizing lock screen notifications on 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, notifications, lock-screens

Is there an app that makes it possible to have email, Facebook, etc. notifications displayed on the unlock screen, the way that voicemail and text message notifications are displayed?

Comment: Some custom lockscreens can do that, but they're not fully secure.